# tsql trigger for copy older data before update

Tags: t-sql, triggers

i need help to create a trigger, i have a database with this table: test01(id, name, id_parent)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test01](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_test01] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)
```

when an update is executed i need to copy the update row in the same table.

Example data before update

```
id,  name, id_parent
1 , 'bob', null
2 , 'jak', null
```

if i send:

> update test01 set name='newbob' where id=1

i need this result

```
id,  name,    id_parent
1 , 'newbob', null    <---- updated row
2 , 'jak',    null
3 , 'bob',    1       <---- copy of previous row with id_parent referenced to the updated row
```

i need help to create a trigger for this.

my non working version:

```
CREATE TRIGGER testtrg 
   ON  test01
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    insert into test01 
    select * from inserted

END
GO
```

Comment: `inserted` contains the data you **inserted** (hint is in the name ;) ). If you want the data that was previously in the table, you want the `deleted` pseudo table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works.  you needed to map the id into the id_parent column

```
drop table test01
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test01](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [id_parent][int] NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_test01] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
   [id] ASC
));

insert into test01   (name,id_parent)
values('bob', null),('jak', null)
select * from test01

CREATE TRIGGER testtrg 
ON  test01
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   insert into test01(name,id_parent) 
   select name,id from inserted

END

update test01 set name='bob2' where id=1
select * from test01
```

output:

```
id  name    id_parent
1   bob NULL
2   jak NULL
3   bob2    1
```